# Modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH JAVA_LIBRARY and CLASSPATH in hadoop job

Tags: linux, apache, hadoop, classpath, hdfs

I need to modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH and CLASSPATH before running hadoop  job at cluster. In LD_LIBRARY_PATH and JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH i need to add location of some jars which are required while running the job, As these jars are available at my cluster, similar with CLASSPATH.

I have a 3 NODE cluster, I need to modify this LD_LIBRARY_PATH and CLASSPATH for all the 3 data nodes in such a way that jars available at my cluster node at added to classpath, so that the following jar are available while running the job as i am avoiding jar distribution while running the job to use all ready available jar on cluster nodes. I have tried the given below options

1.I have tried modifying hadoop-env.sh to modify CLASSPATH

```
export HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS="-classpath:/opt/oracle/oraloader-2.0.0-2/jlib/
```

but the above thing modify HADOOP_CLASSPATH not the CLASSPATH

1. For LD_LIBRARY_PATH and JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH i have tired adding given below property in mapred-site.xml as suggested a my place but that didn't work.

   < property >

   < name >mapred.child.env< /name >

   < value >JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/oraloader-2.0.0-2/lib/< /value >

   < value >LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/oraloader-2.0.0-2/lib/< /value >

   < description>User added environment variables for the task tracker child processes. Example : 1) A=foo This will set the env variable A to foo 2) B=$B:c This is inherit tasktracker's B env variable.
   < /description>

   < /property>

I have also restarted my all 3 data nodes,all tasktrakers and 2 NAMENOdes. Still these variables are not set and my hadoop job is not able to find all those jar files required  for running the test.

ERROR LOG::

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   oracle.i18n.text.OraDateFormat    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)

When i do echo HADOOP_CLASSPATH at my cluster nodes, all the required for running hadoop job are coming. But i think the following jars need to be added in JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH but it not coming.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your previous question on this, and my answer were moved to superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/513221/modify-ld-library-path-and-classpath-on-cluster-node-before-running-a-hadoop-job

Comment: @ChrisWhite I have tried the following thing, so that these jars are available while running the job. Can you please suggest what i am suppose to do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel.

If your implementation uses `ToolRunner` (which you really should use if you implement map-reduce in Java) then you can use `-libjars jar1,jar2` to ship your jars to the cluster.

Check out "Side Data Distribution" section in "Hadoop: The definitive guide" by Tom White.

Comment: HI Yevgen,
I think -libjars will copied the ship the jars to cluster and will copied to distributed cache as I don't want to sent the jar, instead i want to use jars which are already present at cluster nodes

EG:suppose i have directory
/dir1/dis2/* where all the jars required to run hadoop job are present at cluster nodes. I wann to add there jars to class path so that these jars are available.

Comment: @AshishSharma Copy the jars first to the HDFS and add them to the classpath in your jobrunner class via: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html#addFileToClassPath%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem%29

Comment: @LorandBendig I don't have access to actual code so cann't modify the class you mentioned. I simply have a command which will run the hadoop job on my cluster node. I need to add few of the jar available at cluster nodes while running the hadoop job.

Comment: @AshishSharma I don't see how you can add jars while running the job. Another option would be to copy the jars to $HADOOP_HOME/lib on all nodes and restart the cluster

Comment: My understanding is that hadoop-env.sh is a good place to tweak CLASSPATH/LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings for Hadoop cluster (by administrator)

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy I have modified hadoop-env.sh file as mentioned above and also modified mapred-site.xml file at my cluster nodes so that the required jars are available while running the jobs, but this is not working. I have also restarted my all tasktrackers. Can you please suggest how should i proceed now to resolve this.